# How to check the status of cassandra using node.js?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-driver

I am using cassandra-driver module in node.js. My usecase is that I have emit notification in the UI saying "DB is in down state" when Cassandra node goes down due to some reason.

Basically, I should be able to capture the information as soon as the casssandra goes down using cassandra-driver in node.js

Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

client.hosts does not work, for the temporary solution I am using

```
client.on('log', (level, className, message, furtherInfo) => {

if(level === 'error' && ['NoHostAvailableError', 'OperationTimedOutError'].includes(furtherInfo.name)) {

emitNotification('DB_IS_DOWN');

});
```

If any one has better solution,  you are highly welcome.

**Note: This solution works for me very well !!**

Answer (score 0):

You can either periodically [check the `client.hosts` for nodes that are down](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.3/features/metadata/#cluster-and-schema-metadata). Or maybe it's better to [define hooks like `hostDown`, etc.](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.3/api/class.Client/), and use them to decide if cluster is not available.

Comment: Thanks Alex, client.hosts does not work  if a node is down after some point of time. Can you give code example of hostDown hooks etc it will be helpful. Thanks in Advance.